# Why doesn't extruding face add thickness?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, extrude

When I try extruding these faces it's still hollow. [This is the turtoriel im following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxttMGqFW7k&t=61s)

[image]

[image]

Comment: By HOLLOW, do you mean beneath the pizza slice? If so, then you probably have selected and extruded the EDGES of the pizza slice and not it's FACES. The tutorial also didn't mention if it was the Face or Edge of the pizza slice that was extruded.

Comment: Is this potentially a replicate of this issue?
"Extruding, other side does not have face":
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6271/extruding-other-side-does-not-have-face

Comment: @OgunlesiTaiwo the same thing happens when i use faces

Comment: Hey, @Louis. It appears I have also come across the same issue on my current project. Were you then able to find a solution to yours? If Yes, please share it. Thanks.

Comment: @OgunlesiTaiwo hey, i just had to watch the turtoriel a bit longer, the hollow side was under the Pizza in the turtoriel so it looked like it had two Sides. He copied the top and connected it beneath the pizza